# Статическое внедрение dll в сборку

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assembly

Нужно при старте Win-приложения загружать dll, но делать это необходимо **изнутри** сборки (именно потому статическая загрузка)!

Частичное решение уже есть: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971418/c-sharp-embed-dll-in-exe-filenotfoundexception

Но, что и закономерно, в моем случае также вылетает это же исключение:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "SevenZipSharp, Version=0.64.3890.29348, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=20de82c62b055c88" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.

Пробовал добавлять эту dll и через ресурсы (тогда программа даже отказывается стартовать из-за того, что не находит в нужном месте эту dll, а именно в папке "bin/Debug/...") и через "Сборка - Add - Existing Item..." (так стартует, но до загрузки формы получаю вышеописанное исключение).

Код, находящийся в файле Program.cs, имеет вид (практически идентичен тому, который рассматривается по ссылке и оставлен без ответа; также я пробовал изменять его, следуя указаниям из различных источников):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            string assemblyName = args.Name.Split(',').First();
            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1." + assemblyName + ".dll"))
            {
                byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Также пробовал в свойствах dll (добавленной через "Existing Item...") выбирать различные варианты "Build Action". Результат отрицательный.

Также вариант с программой ILMerge (http://habrahabr.ru/post/126089/) не подходит.

Как указать системе, что я хочу обратиться и загрузить dll по пути изнутри сборки, а не извне?

Comment: Что именно вы пытаетесь сделать? Встроить SevenZipSharp внутрь своего приложения, без внешней сборки?

Comment: А почему «не подходит» вариант с ILMerge? Вы уверены, что «не подходит», а не «не вышло»?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот полные шаги:

1. Добавить `SevenZipSharp.dll` в проект через Add Existing Item, выставить Build Type = Embedded Resource
2. Добавить `SevenZipSharp.dll` в References. Выставить у референса Copy Local = false - чтобы избежать копирования в bin.
3. Упомнятуть класс где-то в `Form_Load` (чтобы произошла попытка подгрузки dll) - у вас это явно сделано:

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor c = new SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor();
   }
   ```
4. Аккуратно обработать `CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve`:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Reflection;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
   {
       static class Program
       {
           [STAThread]
           static void Main()
           {
               AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

               Application.EnableVisualStyles();
               Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
               Application.Run(new Form1());
           }

           private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
           {
               var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name;
               if (assemblyName == "SevenZipSharp")
               {
                   using (var stream = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
                       "WindowsFormsApplication7." + assemblyName + ".dll"))
                   {
                       byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
                       stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                       return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   return null;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Это минимальный рабочий пример. Если не работает - запускайте под отладчиком. Скорее всего вы не угадали с именем ресурса, и `GetManifestResourceStream` возвращает `null`. Убедитесь, что тип у айтема выставлен именно в Embedded Resource (а не просто в Resource). Просмотреть имена всех доступных ресурсов можно прямо в отладчике, вызовом

```
typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
```

Проект целиком на гитхабе: https://github.com/PashaPash/SevenZipSharp-Embedded

Comment: Спасибо! Всё отлично работает. Но, весьма странным показалось следующее: на созданной ранее сборке, на которой экспериментировал, ничего сразу не получилось, хотя всё сделал, как описано Вами. А вот когда я создал полностью новый solution и выполнил точь-в-точь эти же шаги - всё взлетело! О.о

Comment: @vitaliklibra скоре всего где-то чуть с именем ресурса не угадали. я тоже не угадал с первого раза, пришлось чуть поотлаживать :)

Comment: Очень признателен за обратную связь) Этот вариант не отбрасываю, также как и то, что где-то мог сам удалить нужный системе файл сборки. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @vitaliklibra поставьте отметку V слева от ответа - вам за это 2 репутации дадут )