# Динамический вызов SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#

Добрый день! 
Что-то непозволительно долго ковыряюсь с казалось бы ерундовой затеей...

Задача - динамически загрузить сборку SevenZipSharp.dll ([известная библиотека для работы с архивами](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/)), затем создать экземпляр `SevenZipExtractor(string ArchiveFullName)` и вызвать метод `ExtractArcive(string directory)`, который должен распаковать указанный архив в заданную директорию.

Делаю так:

```
//Так как зависимостей у либы нет, то гружу сборку из ресурсов в массив байт, минуя выгрузку в файл.
var resourceBuffer = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resnameSevenZipSharpLibrary) as byte[];
Assembly _SevenZipSharp = Assembly.Load(resourceBuffer);

//Сборка успешно загружается, получаем инфо по типу SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor
var extaractorClassType = _SevenZipSharp.GetType(SevenZip_ExtractorClassName);


string ArchiveFullPath = "D:\\TEST.ARJ";
//Пробуем создать экземпляр класса, передав одному из конструкторов в качестве аргумента полное имя архива:
var Extractor = Activator.CreateInstance(extaractorClassType, new object[] { ArchiveFullPath });
```

Собственно, тут и падает приложение с ошибкой:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException ("Адресат вызова создал исключение.")
...
Inner excepton: System.TypeInitializationException ("Инициализатор типа "SevenZip.SevenZipLibraryManager" выдал исключение.")

в SevenZip.SevenZipLibraryManager.LoadLibrary(Object user, Enum format)
в SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.Init(String archiveFullName)
в SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor..ctor(String archiveFullName)

Inner excepton: System.ArgumentException ("Путь имеет недопустимую форму.")`
```

Если задать, к примеру, путь как `ArchiveFullPath = "TEST.ARJ"`, то он выдаст ошибку файл не найден (что совершенно логично, ибо в `CurrentDirectory` архива нет). Т.е. путь в виде краткого имени файла он вроде как прожевывает, а вот если указать диск, то уже не хочет.

Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой, или может быть, что-то не то творю. Замылился уже глаз, пробовал по-разному, через `GetConstructor`, например.

Разумеется, до вызова метода `ExtractArchive` дело даже не доходит.

Да, я знаю, что можно добавить в проект еще до компиляции ссылку на сборку, и беспрепятственно использовать классы из namespace SevenZip, просьба такой вариант не предлагать. Можно было бы сделать так - не парил бы мозг и сделал бы сразу.

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Если вызывать легально - проблема проявляется?

Comment: Нет, проблемы не появляется, иначе не было бы вопроса. В тестовом проекте на либу ссылаюсь через Referencies, вполне себе работает вот так без всяких проблем: `using (var arj = new SevenZipExtractor(arjArchiveName))  { arj.ExtractArchive(targetDir); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ситуация решилась несколько иначе, желаемый результат был достигнут иным путём. Решение было навеяно [вот этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457518/222168), но не затрагивает **Build Action** и **EmbeddedResource** вкупе с событием `AssemblyResolve`.

Итого:

1. SevenZipSharp.dll была приаттачена к ресурсам самого проекта, т.е. внутрь сборки: <kbd>Project</kbd> --> <kbd>Properties</kbd> --> <kbd>Resources</kbd> наравне с 7z.dll, которая необходима для работы SevenZipSharp.dll.
2. В ссылках на сборки (References) была добавлена ссылка на файл SevenZipSharp.dll. В свойствах ссылки было задано **Copy Local = False** дабы при билде проекта эта сборка не копировалась туда же, где и основной бинарник проекта. Всё, теперь можно использовать namespace SevenZip в коде и создавать любые объекты без привлечения рефлексии.
3. Был написан несложный метод, который берет и извлекает ресурсы из проекта на диск в виде файлов. Да, можно было напрямую сохранять каждый ресурс, обращаясь к нему, например, так: `byte[] lib = Properties.Resources.SevenZipSharp;`. Но мне захотелось сделать выгрузку в файл по имени ресурса и повторно еще использовать этот метод:

   ```
   private static bool ExtractBinaryResourceToFile(string resourceName, string filename)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName))
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException(resourceName, "Не указано имя извлекаемого ресурса.");
       }
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException(filename, "Не указано имя файла, в который сохранять ресурс.");
       }
       var resourceBuffer = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceName) as byte[];
       if (resourceBuffer == null) return false;
       try
       {
           File.WriteAllBytes(filename, resourceBuffer);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           throw e; //Поскольку в приложении есть обработчик ошибок, то просто генерим ошибку, которую он отловит.
       }
       return File.Exists(filename);
   }
   ```
4. Работа с SevenZipSharp осуществляется довольно просто, примерно так:

   ```
           using (var arj = new SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor(ArchiveFullPath))
           {
               arj.ExtractArchive(TargetDir);
           }
   ```
5. PROFIT!!1

Поскольку у меня в проекте есть ряд ограничений (решение должно выглядеть в виде ОДНОЙ DLL, которая, в свою очередь, является модулем приложения), то пришлось поступать таким вот образом. Поэтому-то приходится при инициализации своего модуля распаковывать руками из ресурсов и 7z.dll, и SevenZipSharp.dll в ту же папку, где и находится основной модуль (тот самый, в котором и хранится всё это добро).

Тогда вот этом случае обработчик `AssemblyResolve` основного приложения видит библиотеку SevenZipSharp.dll, а та, в свою очередь, прекрасно видит 7z.dll даже без явного указания пути в `SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath()`.

Возможно, я что-то упустил, но иного разрешения ситуации придумать не смог. Ибо даже если загружать сборку SevenZipSharp.dll напрямую из ресурсов в `AssemblyResolve`, но такое вряд ли прокатит с неуправляемой 7z.dll.

Оттого сначала при инициализации моей сборки происходит выгрузка необходимых библиотек из ресурсов основной сборки в файлы.